# Find $ \int {dt\over 2t+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

a simple question, but I'm stuck anyway:
How to integrate this:
$$ \int {dt\over 2t+1}  = ? $$
Is it simply:
 $\ln|2t +1| $
or do I need Chain rule like: $$\ln|2t +1| \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(2t + 1) $$

Comment: Differentiate $\ln |2t+1|$ and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I forgot about: dy/dx = u'/u formula, for y = ln u, you helped me in refreshing my memory. I will wait a little longer, and accept the answer with most upvotes.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer you think helped you the most. If you can't decide which helped you the most, then do as you intend. Personally I like to accept the earlier answer in case of a tie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea about the "form" of the integral, but recall, we need to account for the chain-rule **before** integrating, by u-substitution for example.

In general, when you have an integral of the form $\int \dfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \,dt$
your result will indeed be: $$\int \dfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \,dx = \ln|f(t)| + C$$

In your case, we have $f(t) = u =2t + 1$. Now, we need $f'(t):\; du = 2 dt\iff \frac 12 du = dt$, so we need to obtain the form $$\int \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,dt$$ which we can obtain directly, or through substitution:

$$\int \frac{dt}{2t + 1} = \frac 12 \int \underbrace{\frac{2\,dt}{2t + 1}}_{\dfrac{f't}{f(t)} dt} \quad \overset{\text{substitute}}{=} \quad \frac 12 \int \frac{du}{u} \quad = \quad  \frac 12\ln|u| + C = \cdots$$

Comment: @GitGud Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Gets a thumbs up! +1

Answer (score 3):

This should be the straight-cut way to integrate the expression.

As Cameron Buie responded, let $u = 2t + 1$.  Then, $du = 2 dt$.  Making that substitution for the integral, we have:

$$\int \frac{du}{2u}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \ln|u| + \mathrm{c}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \ln|2t + 1| + \mathrm{c}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the substitution $u=2t+1$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $u=2t+1$. I think it will help you.